# Advice on a recipe

Tags: grain, recipe-formulation

I have the following grains available and was wondering what would be the general idea of doing my own recipe.

- 0.5kg Amber Malt
- 0.5kg Maris Otter
- 0.5kg Halcyon
- 1kg Pale Malt
- 1kg Caramel Dark
- 3kg Red-x
- 1kg Black Malt
- 1kg Brewing Sugars (dextrose)

I would like to do some sort of red tinted beer but I fear that I don't have enough of the Red-X grains. My fermenter can handle 20 liters. That is the amount of wort I'm aiming for.

Also is the brewing sugars necessary? What would one kg brewing sugars do to a 20 liter batch of wort? Is the sugars a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have enough Red-X. Especially with added caramel, it tends to bring some reddish hues. Carered would be best for this, but all caramel can help.

## Get your tools

For recipe formulation, I really like [Brewtarget](http://www.brewtarget.org/). It's free, and it lets you see for yourself answers to questions like:

> What would one kg brewing sugars do to a 20 liter batch of wort?

Also, it lets you select style you like, read about it, and formulate recipe that will at least keep main parameters of that style.

## Malts you have that are good for reddish ale:

- Maris Otter - no colour to speak of, but solid base malt.
- Pale - looks like some generic base malt, again no colour contribution to praise or worry about. Sugar source.
- Amber - between base malt and red, will not hurt.
- Caramel Dark - Try to steep a bit of it in cold water and see colour. If it's reddish, as I expect it to be, it's good. If it's brown, don't use it for red ales.

## Malts you have I would not use:

- Fawcett Halcyon Pale Malt - floor malting tends to give more browns than reds as far as I know. I might be wrong, maybe there was other factors, but I wouldn't waste it on this recipe.
- Brewing Sugars - You have enough sugar in your malt. Leave this for priming
- Black Malt - roasted *malt* tends to get brown. Roasted *unmalted barley* brings reds.

## What I would do:

I would aim for red variation about Best/Premium Bitter style. Grain bill:

- Red-X 3kg
- Pale 1kg
- Maris Otter 0,5kg
- Caramel 250g

You would get red / copper colour, 1.050 OG (depending on your mash efficiency), good base for English hops if my guess is accurate.About 4.5% ABV, good for easy drinking. Not in style (nothing with malt as modern as Red X can be), but close to.

Here is [Brewtarget file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6whfGcSBABQeFlwbTFIQm1saUE/view?usp=sharing) for this.

---

Adding sugar in anything but Belgian styles is not a good idea. Unless, for some reason, you want to replicate style that allowed sugar usage - but if you do, you don't have to ask.

Keep it for priming, there it's pretty good.

Comment: "Adding sugar in anything but Belgian styles is not a good idea." Where does this come from.  Many English style traditionally used sugars.  And there is nothing wrong with using sugars to make a higher gravity beer, nor is there nothing wrong with using sugars to dry out a beer.  Sugars are a tool just like the rest of the ingredients. That was a long post to sort of drop the ball at the goal line.

Comment: @brewchez have you read any further than the quote? Especially part **Unless, for some reason, you want to replicate style that allowed sugar usage**. Because your comment about English styles indicate you commented without reading that.

Comment: I read the whole comment.  That first part is just too absolute even when followed with... 'well its OK sometimes'. Which you final comment suggests about not having to ask.